# How to serve robots.txt and sitemap.xml on netlify?

Tags: netlify

I have a site with a classic SPA redirect, like so:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

The problem is that when I try to submit a sitemap to google search console, placed on the root of my site, it always renders `/index.html`. I've tried redirecting `/sitemap.xml` to `/static/sitemap.xml` and nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the custom rules in Netlify for your `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`.
I've just created a `__redirects` file on the same level as my `index.html` with the following contents:

```
/robots.txt    /robots.txt   200
/sitemap.xml    /sitemap.xml   200
/*    /index.html   200
```

After doing that, when you access `yoursite.com/robots.txt` you should see that the SPA router does not work and Netlify gives you a 404. That means the redirect worked.

Now all you need to do it's make sure you have those files in the directory you deploy to Netlify.
If you're using Angular, make sure you add your files in the `angular.json` config, under `assets`:

```json
 "architect": {
        "build": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/_redirects",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ],
...
```